# IO Error 22 python

Tags: python

```
infile1 = open("D:/p/non_rte_header_path.txt","r")
infile2 = open("D:/p/fnsinrte.txt","r")
for line in infile1:
    for item in infile2:
         eachfile = open(line,"r")
```

For the above code I am getting the below error. infile1 contains paths of may files like D:/folder/Src/em.h but here \n is automatically at the end of the path.I am not sure why it happens. Please help.

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: 'D:/folder/Src/em.h\n'
```

Comment: `\n` should give you a clue, you forgot to strip the trailing newline.

Comment: Try to trim `line` before trying to open it.

Comment: You need to strip the new line character so `line.rstip('\n')` will work

Comment: Try `eachfile = open(line.rstrip('\n'), "r")`.

Comment: @EdChum thanks.But if I use the rstrip option, program throws error saying that str does not have attrig rstrip. Please help

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Everyone has provided comments telling you what the problem is but if you are a beginner you probably don't understand why it's happening, so i'll explain that.

Basicly, when opening a file with python, each new line (when you press the Enter Key) is represented by a "\n".

As you read the file, it reads line by line, but unless you remove the "\n", it your line variable will read

> thethingsonthatline\n

This can be useful to see if a file contains multiple lines, but you'll want to get rid of it. Edchum and alvits has given a good way of doing this !

Your corrected code would be :

```
infile1 = open("D:/p/non_rte_header_path.txt","r")
infile2 = open("D:/p/fnsinrte.txt","r")

for line in infile1:
    for item in infile2:
         eachfile = open(line.rstrip('\n'), "r")
```

Comment: thanks all. But if I use the rstrip option, program throws error saying that str does not have attrig rstrip. Please help.

Comment: Hey ! what version of python are you using ?
I just tested this on my pc and it works